# Problem in installing mongodb by wget method in debian

Tags: bash, debian, software-installation, wget, mongodb

I tried `sudo wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc` to install MongoDB.
But the following error occurred `sudo: wget: command not found`. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get -y install wget
```

OR use `curl` if its available

```
curl https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc
```